# create directories within directories with ruby not working

Tags: ruby

Actually I'm trying to create directories within directories. Structure is like this:

```
./SOURCE_APPL/applsource/
./SOURCE_BASIS/basissource/
```

Would like to have the following result after running my script:

```
./SOURCE_APPL/applsource/newDir/
./SOURCE_BASIS/basissource/newDir/
```

I'm using this code:

```
  folders = Dir['SOURCE_*/*/']
  folders.each do
    FileUtils.mkdir_p 'newDir'
  end
```

The folder "newDir" is created only on the Top Directory level "." but not within the mentioned directories. Any idea what the "ruby newby" is doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to build the new folder path and create it. This should work:

```
folders = Dir['SOURCE_*/*/']
folders.each do |folder|
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.join(folder, 'newDir'))
end
```